# Add button next to TextView programmatically

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a ListView of TextViews of countries and I did a OptionsMenu item after  clicking a short press on one of the TextViews it will delete the pressed textview.
I would like to know if there is a way to do that when I press the item "Delete Country"
a button will appear next to every TextView like in iphone example 
[image: delete]

the ListView is created by an Adapter.
I don't need the whole answer just the concept of how can it be done (delete button that is created next to every TextView after you choose from Optionsmenu to delete a country).

```
public class CountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



private Context mContext;
protected Vector<Country> mVector;
protected SQLiteDatabase mDb;

public void setmContext(Context mContext){
    this.mContext = mContext;
}


public CountryAdapter(Context mContext){
    this.mContext = mContext;

    mVector = new Vector<Country>();

    CountryOpenHelper helper = new CountryOpenHelper(mContext);
    mDb = helper.getWritableDatabase();


    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES", null);

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){

        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    do {
        Country country = new Country();
        country.setmCountryIndex(cursor.getInt(0));
        country.setmCountryName(cursor.getString(2));
        country.setmCountryTextSize(cursor.getInt(1));
        country.setmCountryColor(cursor.getInt(3));
        mVector.add(country);

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());




}


public Vector<Country> getmVector() {
    return mVector;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mVector.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv;
    if(convertView == null){
        tv = new TextView(mContext);
    }else{
        tv = (TextView) convertView;
    }

    tv.setText(mVector.get(position).getmCountryName());
    tv.setTextColor(mVector.get(position).getmCountryColor());
    tv.setTextSize(mVector.get(position).getmCountryTextSize());



    return tv;
}
public void ChangeColor(int newcolor, String name) {

    mDb.execSQL("update COUNTRIES set color = " + newcolor + " where name = '" + name + "' " );




}
public void addCountry(int mId, String myCountry, int myColorNum){
    mDb.execSQL("insert into countries values(" + mId + " , ' " + myCountry+"' , "+ myColorNum + ")");
}

public void delete(int position) {
    int mDeletedId = mVector.get(position).getmCountryIndex();
    mVector.remove(position);
    mDb.execSQL("DELETE FROM countries WHERE id ="+mDeletedId);

}


public void ChangeTextSize(int textSize, int mIndex) {
    System.out.println(textSize);
    System.out.println(mIndex);
    mDb.execSQL("update COUNTRIES set font = " + textSize + " where id =" + mIndex);


}
```

}

I want when i click from optionMenu "Remove Country"
it will programmatically add delete button(or something else) next to every TextView and all those buttons will apply the same Method(delete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create Button in XML file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/row_category_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Add"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row_category_name"
       android:textColor="@color/black"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. Create a View holder and Add button in the Adapter class:

   ```
   ViewHolder holder ;

   if(view ==null){
           view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.___, null);
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.____);
           holder.img =(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.______); 
           holder.btn =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button); 
           view.setTag(holder);
       }

   class ViewHolder{
       TextView tv;
       ImageView img;
       Button btn;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to add the button programmatically and making a mess, try this.

I'm assuming your using a custom Array Adapter for the ListView. Add the button to the row and align it to the right of the text view.

Make the delete button invisible with `android:visibility="gone"` in the xml file defining the row layout.

```
textView1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        deleteButton.setVisibility(true);
 deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onClick(View v) {
        //delete the row here
    }
});
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I create the row dynamicly from an other activity for result I add more text views how can I make a delete button that will automaticly be right to every text view on demand, I mean on every row ..

Comment: @YonatanBalas Why do you want to create the rows dynamically? Why can't you just make a row.xml file and assign that to the adapter. Makes life a whole lot simpler. If you still want to go by your method, you'll have to inflate a relative layout for the row, then add the textview and button.

Comment: Yeah i understand what your saying, we just learned this now on class and my teacher gave your answer, thanks mate :]